# Why I get 'list' object has no attribute 'items'?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using Python 2.7, I have this list:

```
qs = [{u'a': 15L, u'b': 9L, u'a': 16L}]
```

I'd like to extract values out of it.

i.e. `[15, 9, 16]`

So I tried:

```
result_list = [int(v) for k,v in qs.items()]
```

But instead, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I'm wondering why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
result_list = [int(v) for k,v in qs[0].items()]
```

qs is a list, qs[0] is the dict which you want!

Comment: But it does not output `[15, 9, 16]`

Comment: @Slsam It does. Tried it.

Comment: For sure it will not for `qs = [{u'a': 15L, u'b': 9L, u'a': 16L}]` as you mentioned in the original question

Comment: The dictionary only contains 2 entries, as each must have a unique key, and `'a'` was used twice. `'a':15` is not in the dictionary. Also the order of the items is not necessarily the same as the order in which they were added.

Answer (score 6):

More generic way in case `qs` has more than one dictionaries:

```
[int(v) for lst in qs for k, v in lst.items()]
```

--

```
>>> qs = [{u'a': 15L, u'b': 9L, u'a': 16L}, {u'a': 20, u'b': 35}]
>>> result_list = [int(v) for lst in qs for k, v in lst.items()]
>>> result_list
[16, 9, 20, 35]
```

Comment: Great tip. I shall use this on. Don't accept it as answer just because it is not direct respose to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the type of the numbers you can simply use:

```
qs[0].values()
```

Answer (score 1):

items is one attribute of dict object.maybe you can try

```
qs[0].items()
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary does not support duplicate keys- So you will get the last key i.e.`a=16` but not the first key `a=15`

```
>>>qs = [{u'a': 15L, u'b': 9L, u'a': 16L}]
>>>qs
>>>[{u'a': 16L, u'b': 9L}]
>>>result_list = [int(v) for k,v in qs[0].items()]
>>>result_list
>>>[16, 9]
```

Comment: This is not right. I can get `[15, 9, 16]` from `[int(v) for k,v in qs[0].items()]
`

Comment: @Jand are you 100% sure? Because in every version of python dictionaries must have unique keys. Perhaps you made a typo in the question and meant the third entry to be `u'c':16L` or similar?

Answer (score 0):

You have a dictionary within a list. You must first extract the dictionary from the list and then process the items in the dictionary.

If your list contained multiple dictionaries and you wanted the value from each dictionary stored in a list as you have shown do this:

```
result_list = [[int(v) for k,v in d.items()] for d in qs]
```

Which is the same as:

```
result_list = []
for d in qs:
    result_list.append([int(v) for k,v in d.items()])
```

The above will keep the values from each dictionary in their own separate list. If you just want all the values in one big list you can do this:

```
result_list = [int(v) for d in qs for k,v in d.items()]
```