# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items' - unittest

Tags: python, list, python-unittest

While learning testing software with Python I'm stuck here:

1. I have an app with the following function:

```
def print_blogs():
    for key, blog in blogs[0].items():
        print("- {}".format(blog))
```

Then I run the test, but it doesn't pass, because of the:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items' error.
```

But it raises another error: expected "- Test by Test by Test Author (0 posts)", but I just get "- Test", so the test fail.

I've also tried:

```
def print_blogs():
    for key, blog in blogs[0].items():
        b = []
        b.append(blog)
        print("- {}".format(b))
```

Without expecting result, as the same error is raised.

In the curs I'm doing I checked with the guy's code and I looks identically. However, on his part the test pass, in my case the test fails.

I'm using Python 3.7

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why I get 'list' object has no attribute 'items'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949856/why-i-get-list-object-has-no-attribute-items) In summary, `blogs[0]` is not a dictionary thus you can't call `.items()` on it.

Comment: If I take away .items(), so: `for key, blog in blogs:`... then I get another error: ValueError: too many values to unpack. If I do `for key, blog in blogs():` then It shows TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: You should add the values of `blog` in the question. Otherwise, we will just be guessing on what it is.

Comment: Thanks, Niel. `blog = Blog('Test', 'Test Author')`.